# Little problem with Telegram in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, telegram, gnome-dash

Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed telegram downloading the tarball from the official webpage and then have entered the commands

```
tar -xvf tsetup.2.7.1.tar
sudo mv Telegram/ /opt/telegram
sudo ln -sf /opt/telegram/Telegram /usr/bin/telegram
```

What I don't like is 1) the fact that I do not have an icon among all the applications that appear when the Show application button is clicked; 2) Starting telegram with the command telegram form the command line, telegram opens but I get the errors

```
[ALSOFT] (EE) Failed to set real-time priority for thread: Operation not permitted (1)
error: : cannot open
error: : cannot open
error: : cannot open
```

Is there a way to have an icon and avoid the awkward appearance of the errors?
I have also tried to install telegram from snap or using ubuntu-software center, but I had to remove it because when sending a pdf file in attachment to a message, the computer would freeze and I was forced to stop it by pressing the on button (this is another problem....probably for another questions)

Comment: Why don't you install one of the Telegram clients already available in the repositories or snap store?

Comment: I think I have clarified in my question that installing via snap or software-ubuntu center gives me a problem because the computer freezes when trying to send a file in attachment to a telegram message

Comment: Installing from source is no guarantee to not have the same problem. And the problem may be related to any number of situations like a file too big, not enough free memory/swap, etc.

Comment: Could you please give some details about your computer? What is the CPU? How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 5):

To install Telegram from deb-package use [famous good PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eatareao/+archive/ubuntu/telegram?field.series_filter=focal) as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install telegram
```